# how to check if extension if varibale contains some file extensions

Tags: php

My variable $FileExtension gives me the extension of a file.
Now i want to check for some image extensions.

I tried this:

```
if($FileExtension == array('jpg', 'png', 'gif)) {
// do something
}
```

what is the correct way?

Comment: Use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(in_array($FileExtension,array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: Works prefect. Thanks